# How to compare vector<float> and float*

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, stdvector

I need to compare two float arrays for equality of their values. I know they have the same length. But unfortunately the arrays are not the same type:

```
bool compare(vector<float> A, float* B) 
{
  // what do I write here?
}
```

How can I do it? I am not that familiar with pointers.

Comment: You'll need to know the size of `B` as well unless you're going to assume they're the same and potentially go out of bounds.

Comment: Both can be accessed the same way: `A[i]` and `B[i]` so your job should be pretty easy. That being said, be prepared for `float` values to differ by a tiny amount due to the way floating point values are represented. +/- a tiny epsilon is typically considered "equal".

Comment: @tadman The OP does mention that the sizes are the same.

Comment: @cigien Yeah, I just mention that it's tradition to include a length for pointers so you can confirm rather than assume.

Comment: @tadman Ah, I see. Yeah, that's good advice, for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot everybody! This is how I did it now, since I know that the two vectors have the same length.

```
bool compareSerAndPar(std::vector<float> Ser, float* Par, int size)
{
    float eps = 0.01f;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        float temp = fabs(Ser[i] - Par[i]);
        if(temp > eps)
        {
        return false;
        }
    
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `std::equal` to compare the ranges, even though they have different types, like this:

```
bool compare(std::vector<float> A, float* B) // [[ precondition: lengths are the same ]]
{
  return std::equal(std::begin(A), std::end(A), B);
}
```

This relies on both ranges having the same size, which seems to apply in your case.

Note also that comparing `float` values for exact equality is not a good idea. You might want to use a custom comparator that checks if the values are close to each other within some tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach you could take. Its from scratch so no external functions are used.

```
bool compare(std::vector<float> A, float* B)
{
            
         float sizeOfBlock = sizeof(B) / sizeof(float) + 1;
         
         if(A.size() == sizeOfBlock)
         {
             for(int I = 0; I < A.size(); I++)
             {
                 if(A[I] != B[I])
                 {
                    return false;
                 }
                
             }
         }
         else
         {
            return false;
         }
       return true;
}
```